# Organizar meses do eixo X

Tags: python, gráfico, matplotlib

Estou fazendo gráficos no formato boxplot de novembro a março e gostaria que o eixo x ficasse com a seguinte ordem [11, 12, 1, 2, 3], mas ele sempre começa no mês 1, alguém conseguiria me ajudar?
Também gostaria de deixar os valores inteiros ou deixar os nomes dos meses ao invés dos números.

```
fig = plt.figure( figsize=(17, 5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)


Monthly_Returns.boxplot(column='soma_dia', by='month',grid=True,
                showfliers=True, boxprops=boxprops3, medianprops=medianprops, patch_artist=True, ax=ax1)

Monthly_Returns.boxplot(column='dia_comparação', by='month',grid=True,
                showfliers=True, boxprops=boxprops4, medianprops=medianprops, patch_artist=True, ax=ax2)

fig.suptitle('Média Mensal do Acumulado da Precipitação Diária', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

ax1.set_xlabel('Mês')
ax2.set_xlabel('Mês')
ax1.set_ylabel('Precipitação (mm/h)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Precipitação (mm/h)')

ax1.set_title('Presença de Vento de Oeste')
ax2.set_title('Sem Vento de Oeste')

ax1.set_ylim([0, 22])
ax2.set_ylim([0, 22])

plt.show()
```

Resultando em:
[Link do gráfico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqkC4.png)

Answer (score 2):

Para seguir a ordem dos meses 11,12,1,2,3 , precisara especificar a ordem e inclui -la.

Adicionando os meses na ordem especifica,uma lista com os valores a ser usado

```
meses = [11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
```

O uso da função [pd.Categorical()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)  vai modificar a coluna **month** em categoria com as ordens dos meses, `sort_values()` ira ordenar o DataFrame.
Categorical é utilizada para mudar a variável de dados para uma variável categórica.

```
Monthly_Returns['month'] = pd.Categorical(Monthly_Returns['month'], categories=meses, ordered=True)

Monthly_Returns = Monthly_Returns.sort_values('month')
```

organizando o código: determinando a ordem dos rótulos.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
```

A implementação da função [**set_xticklabels**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html), é encarregada de trocar os rótulos do eixo **x** default para a lista  `[11, 12, 1, 2, 3]`.
Quando a função `set_xticklabels` é invocada  os rótulos do eixo **x** vão ser alterados pela lista **meses**.

```
    ax1.set_xticklabels(meses)
```

O boxplot estipula qual sera ordem dos rótulos no eixo.

```
Monthly_Returns.boxplot(column='dia_comparação', by='month', grid=True,
                        showfliers=True, boxprops=boxprops4, medianprops=medianprops,
                        patch_artist=True, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xticklabels(meses)
```

Conclusão do codigo:

```
fig.suptitle('Média Mensal do Acumulado da Precipitação Diária', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

ax1.set_xlabel('Mês')
ax2.set_xlabel('Mês')
ax1.set_ylabel('Precipitação (mm/h)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Precipitação (mm/h)')

ax1.set_title('Presença de Vento de Oeste')
ax2.set_title('Sem Vento de Oeste')

ax1.set_ylim([0, 22])
ax2.set_ylim([0, 22])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Eu tentei fazer desta maneira e o eixo x realmente ficou na ordem que eu queria, porém os dados não acompanharam, desta forma a média de janeiro ainda ficou na mesma posição mas com a legenda como se fosse novembro

Comment: o que estava acontecendo é que o DataFrame não esta seguindo a ordem dos meses.. inclui esse detalhe pertinente.